# How do I make my bot create / clone another voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted my bot to create a new voice server or just clone another one. "voic" is a var that is contained the voice channel id.

```
voic.voiceChannel.clone(undefined, true, false, 'Needed a clone')
                           // discord example
            .then(clone => console.log(`Cloned ${channel.name} to make a channel called ${clone.name}`))
            .catch(console.error);
          }

TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined.
```

Comment: Looks like `voic` has no attribute `voiceChannel`, any chance you could share what the contents of `voic` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `voic` is an id itself, you will need to get the channel by it's id. You can use `bot.channels.get()` to retrieve the channel.

```
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.channels.get(voic).clone(undefined, true, false, 'Needed a clone')
    .then(clone => console.log(`Cloned ${channel.name} to make a channel called ${clone.name}`))
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: and you know how to leave it in the specific topic? he's just showing up there

Comment: I just had a look, just change `clone(undefined, true, false, 'Needed a clone')` to `clone(undefined, true, true, 'Needed a clone')` The change is to the 3rd parameter, which is a flag on whether to clone with the topic or not

Comment: Keep in mind that the clone will *not* be in the original's category or same position.